# Profile communities list - Last list entry is not shown on profile view

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Opening user's communities view, the last entry of the list (the one behind Science Fiction & Fantasy in the screenshot) is not shown correctly.

It is drawn under the bottom menu bar and it's visible only if you pull up the list. It disappear behind the menu bar when you release the pull.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

This will be fixed in 1.4.3 in January.